# 2 views to 1 controller update()

Tags: laravel

I have 2 different views/forms - they are forms where delegates can fill in some information.

view1 allows delegate to fill in one lot of personal info.

view2 allows the delegate to fill in more detailed info.

Both forms have code like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['DelegatesController@update',$delegate->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
```

The problem is that both views lead back to the DelegatesController update() method and, as they both only carry partial personal info in the request, the validation fails.

Is there a way to have 2 update() methods in a Controller, each called by separate views? Or a way for the update() method to tell which view called it?

I have been messing around with different routes & different Controller code and put/patch but cannot get it working - I either get methods not allowed or 1 parameter passed instead of 2 depending on what I try to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why don't you just create two separate methods `update1()` and `update2()` and then just refer them in your views like `DelegatesController@update1` and `DelegatesController@update2`?

If that's not an option, you can try adding some hidden field e.g. `formType`, which will indicate for type of form was sent, and then in the `update()` method of your controller recieve it using `request('formType')`

Comment: I wasn't able to add a complete answer in a comment to you so I posted more info above. I think you might have something there with the hidden field answer - I will research how to do that.

Comment: Hidden field `_method` refers to HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) and there is no PUT2 method, that's why you get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. I was talking about your custom hidden field with a new unique name. 

About the first part, when you create a new controller method you want send requests to, you should add it to your router configuration aswell. Could you please list your routing config for `DelegatesController`?

Comment: The hiddent field method works very well - I just needed to put an extra line into each form:

<input name="FormType" value="viewX" type="hidden">

This allows me to use the same Controller method which is the preferred way for me to do it anyway. 

I did have new route line for the method but even though I tried a few different ways I got the error about the incorrect number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If I create a 2nd method in the Controller with EXACTLY the same parameters as the update() method I get the following error message:

> Too few arguments to function
>
> App\Http\Controllers\DelegatesController::update_bwofeedback(), 1
>   passed and exactly 2 expected

The update() method has these parameters:
public function update(Request $request, $delegateid)
so it is indeed wanting 2 parameters but I havent changed anything at the form end in the view except the method name so I am not sure how it passes 2 parameters to update() but not update2()

For the hidden field I did previously try changing:

```
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
```

to:

```
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT2')}}
```

but I got an error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

I am now thinking that your hidden field might be different to this hidden method? I will investigate whether I can just incorporate a field/variable in each form and have the update() method do different validation based on that field/variable.